# hbase export and import with out creating a new table before importing

Tags: export, hbase

I am trying to use LoadIncrementalHFiles (so that I don't need to create table before importing) to import the exported file.

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Export t2 /user/backup6/test2

hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles   /user/backup6/test2 tb2
```

I get the following error when I try to load it

```
13/03/06 23:18:46 WARN mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles: Bulk load operation did not find any files to load in directory /user/backup6/test2.  Does it contain files in subdirectories that correspond to column family names?
```

on the hdfs directory, I can see 3 folders _SUCESS, _logs/history, part-m-0000 file created by the export step.

When I try to use `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.Import`, it complains that the new table is not there.

Is there a way to do import without creating a new table (i.e. using the exported files only)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Import can only import to an existing table. LoadIncrementalHFiles will create a new table if the table is missing.